# How to remove empty view in Eclipse RCP's "Hello RCP" template

Tags: templates, view, eclipse-rcp

When I create an RCP application plugin project and choose the "Hello RCP" template to create an initial project.

Now, when I add my own new view, the "empty", grayed-out view created by the template is still there, but I cannot see it mentioned anywhere in the extensions. How do I remove it, so that only MY new view is seen in the application window?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that is a view? "Hello RCP" does not create a view (as you've mentioned). You might confuse it with the editor area. To remove it, open your Perspective class and put the following into that:

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false);
}
```